# javascript цикл while

Tags: javascript

нужно получить все степени тройки не превышающие 100.

```
    var x = 3;
    while(x < 100) {
       console.log(x);
       x = x * 3;
    }
```

```
var x = 3;
while(x < 100) {
   console.log(x);
   x = x * 3;
}

 3
 9
 27
 81
243
```

у меня так выдаёт. Почему? Или это глюк гугла?
что я не так написал?

Comment: Выведите что-нибудь после цикла while

Comment: вариант рабочий, странно то что у вас 243 выводит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы запустите этот код в отдельном файле, скажем в Node.js или внутри HTML-страницы, он выдаст правильный результат. Но если вы его запустите в консоли браузера или в REPL Node.js, последняя цифра (`243`) будет результатом не `console.log(x);` — запуск в консоли выводит под конец результат последнего вычисления, так что это будет результат `x = x * 3;`.

В песочнице работает правильно:

```js
'use strict'

var x = 3;
while(x < 100) {
   console.log(x);
   x = x * 3;
}
```

Если вы запустите в консоли этот вариант, то увидите, что после добавочного вывода просто выводится `undefined`, то есть результат, возвращаемый `console.log('End');`.

```js
'use strict'

var x = 3;
while(x < 100) {
   console.log(x);
   x = x * 3;
}
console.log('End');
```